# Probability that a person replies to one of three tasks

Tags: probability

Hello everybody and thank you for joining the discussion.

I'm currently working on a statistical problem that involves responses on a continuous response scale:

Let's say, people are presented with three differently coloured and located dots. 
1.) All of these three dots have colours picked randomly from a colour wheel. Thus, the range of picked colours is between -pi and +pi.
2.) These three dots are randomly located around a circle, so their location is also defined within a range of -pi and +pi.

In summary, each of these items can be defined by a pair of numbers (1="colour angle", 2="angle of location").

Now, we ask the people to remember all three colours and locations by letting them "draw" them on three separate sheets of paper. So we get three pairs of answers (colour angle and a location angle).

So if you know the three colour and location pairs that have been shown in the beginning and you get the sheet of paper on which a person had drawn their first answer, is there a neat way to calculate the probability to which one of the three pairs the answer was related to? And if so, how about with the second and third sheet/answer?

I am very happy for every thought-provoking impulse!

Comment: Notice that this is a purely Q&A site, it is not meant for discussion, or "sharing thoughts", so if this is what you're looking for, it may be a wrong choice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My question, as asked above, is: How to calculate the probability that a person's response is related to one of the three choices when you have two continuous response scales.